# Larger Space After Section for Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, sectioning

I am getting a large space after a section when math immediately follows. How can I make this space the same as if text followed?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test With Text}
This is normal text.
\section*{Test With Math}
\begin{align*}
  a &= bc\\
  d &= ef
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @HarishKumar Thanks! :) I typically agree that that's a bad idea (why I haven't run into the issue until now). This is a special case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>Don't use a display equation right after the section heading.</sub>

Every multi-line display equation environment of the `amsmath` package, including `align*`, carries `\abovedisplayskip` above it and `\belowdisplayskip` below it. What you see in your case is the former, i.e., `\abovedisplayskip`. While it is not a good idea to have a display equation right after a heading, you may make this zero locally inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\section*{Test With Text}
This is normal text.
\section*{Test With Math}
\bgroup                                  %% open the group
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}       %% effective inside the group    
\begin{align*}
  a &= bc\\
  d &= ef
\end{align*}
\egroup                                  %% end the group

This is some text here just to fill the space.
\begin{align*}
  a &= bc\\
  d &= ef
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. I've deleted my earlier comments, and have taken the liberty of editing the first sentence of your answer. Feel free to edit it some more!

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for the edit. I have to search for the book now :)